# quotation marks are showing up backwards

Tags: html, css, quotes

Whenever I use quotation marks in text to display in my code, both the starting and the ending quotation mark appear as an ending quotation mark. Why could this be happening? I thought it might be the font, but I changed it to multiple different ones and it was still the same. Could something in my code be changing it?

```
#container{

background:transparent;
margin-top:50px;    
border-left:2px #666 solid;
border-right:2px #666 solid;
width:600px;
height:auto;
}
#content{ 
padding:10px;
float: left;
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-top:150px;
border:1px #000 solid;
margin-top:0px;
background-color:transparent;
line-height:0px;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-left:40px;
width:500px;
height:auto;
}
.text{
background:#efefef;
color: #000;
text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:20px;
width:480px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

That is all the css that is targeting this, here is an example image of what is being shown
[image]

Comment: Without a specific example it’s completely impossible to say what’s happening.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: I posted all the relevant css and gave a picture example of what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine this is caused by the text editor you're using to edit the HTML.  Microsoft Word, for example, will automatically convert `"Hello, world"` to `“Hello, world”` (with `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`) which isn't valid markup.

CSS changes the rendering of the HTML. It does not change the HTML itself. Applying CSS to a HTML file with `<p class="paragraph">` will not magically convert the HTML to `<p class=“paragraph”>`. Furthermore, styling `script` tags would be senseless.

The only way this would actually occur with CSS ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEXkB/)) is if firstly your HTML was something like:

```
<body>
    <p>
        &lt;script src=<span>"</span>blah<span>"</span>&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    </p>
</body>
```

And your accompanying CSS was something like:

```
span { font-size:0; }
span:after { content: "“"; font-size:16px; }
```

But I'm assuming that isn't the case at all here.

Comment: yeah, that's not in my css, i just don't understnad